# Spring Security OAuth2 endpoint to allow SavedRequestHandler to capture original request

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0

Using Spring Security 6 OAuth2 with spring boot I have a working login using Okta as an Authorization Server. How do you get a SavedRequest handler to capture the original request before the login attempt occurs?